# Cannot get Fragment data because of Fragment Life cycle

Tags: android, android-fragments

Using Tabs means using fragments, and for some reason fragments have new steps in their life cycle, like `onAttach(Activity)`.
My fragment fills up some maps from the resources, and it is done on `onAttach()` instead of the fragment constructor; because in the constructor `getResources()` throws an exception due to the lack of Activity yet.

The fragment is created on `MainActivity` like this:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    switch( tab.getPosition() ) {
    case 0:
        if( fragmentTab0 == null ) {
            fragmentTab0 = new MyFragment();
            setTabText(0, ((MyFragment)fragmentTab0).getMyName());
        } 
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContent, fragmentTab0, "TAB0");
        break;
```

Here lies my problem, in the call to the fragment method `getMyName()` which uses the maps I mentioned before to get a string. The call to `getMyName()` is executed before the fragment's `onAttach()` and the maps are not ready yet.
I am sure I can find a convoluted way to get the name (actually I tried already to pass the activity to the fragment's constructor and built the maps there, and it works, but it goes against the fragment philosophy).

I would have thought that the activity should be visible during Fragment constructor, since the fragments are created from the activity they're going to be eventually attached, so there is no point in delaying the activity attachment.
I also would have thought that the call to `new MyFragment()` should return after `onAttach()` is done. But it returns right after the constructor is done.

Therefore I feel not comfortable with the situation and I wonder if I am using fragments the wrong way, if so, the question is, how am I supposed to do it right to be able to call `getMyName()` there.

Note: From the fragment [life cycle diagram](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) it is clear that `onAttach()` and `onDetach()` are indistiguishable from `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` respectively, so I question if they are really necessary.

Comment: Agreeing with j__m, your apps consists of tabs. If I am the host of the 5 tabs, I should know the name of the 5 tabs.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib What if the tabs are "Food", "Plastic", "Cars" and the fragment on each tab decides which food, which plastic and which car, and you want to reflect that choice in each tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onAttach()` is not invoked until the fragment transaction is committed.  Until then, a fragment has no reference to the creating `Activity` unless you pass it such a reference.  Passing that reference is probably the cleanest way to implement what you're trying to do.

Generally in Android the title is dictated by the containing activity, not the fragment.  For example, a `PreferenceActivity`'s xml headers file lists titles and their associated fragments; those titles do not appear in the preference xml files used by the `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will then go back to passing the the `Activity` as reference. To clear your doubts: I use a custom tab layout, with primary and secondary text; the primary text is known in advance by the activity. the secondary text is a result of the user choices, so each tab only knows it.

Comment: I don't doubt that that's useful behavior; I may have even done something similar myself at some point.  I was just pointing out why fragments don't seem to be designed to work that way - it's cuz they aren't. = )

Comment: I think I disagree with you on this point. We all know screen real estate is precious in smartphones, using each area to the maximum is what we do. And besides that, if "they" would not want us to do it, there would not be custom layouts for tabs. It is just that out of so much flexibility they sometimes loose track of what is available where.

Comment: I suppose you could consider using a callback interface instead.  That's what the Android preference framework does to handle navigation in the <Preference android:fragment="..."> case (see `PreferenceFragment.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback`).  So instead of the activity trying to query the fragment before it's ready, you can let the fragment call back into the activity in `onAttach()`.